# VSE: Video is imported at incorrect framerate, and setting to correct framerate desyncs audio

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I have a long video that I'd like to insert in the Blender VSE. So I open the default blend file, enable AV-sync, and add the movie strip. Somehow, the video is already the same length as the audio strip.

[image: Strips have same length despite the framerate being incorrect]

The default framerate is ~29.97 fps, but when I open the source in VLC it says the source framerate is about 36.

[image: VLC codec info]

I move the playhead to around halfway through the audio strip in Blender, and it's entirely out of sync with the video. But the strips are already the same length! I tried setting the framerate to what VLC said the source's should be. Now the ends of the strips are nearly ten thousand frames apart and the synchronization problem is even worse.

[image: Strips have very different lengths when correct framerate is set]

I haven't been able to find suitable answers from similar questions on Stack Exchange. They're either "add a speed effect strip" (the strips are already the same length, they're just not in sync) or "make the Blender framerate match the source video framerate" (which I did).

Edit: The question marked this is marked as a duplicate as reached the same solution, but it is really a different question.

Comment: If at all possible, I'd like to avoid using third-party software or addons besides VLC or FFMPEG. But if the only solution involves something else, I'll gladly take that too.

Comment: That should have been among the first things I checked. Thanks! I'm running the source through FFMPEG right now. If it works I'll accept your posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

36.000560 is not a standard frame rate by any means (is this some screen recording or is this done with a cheap phone?). When you find those frame rates it is possible that the recorded video is compressed using variable frame rate. Blender cannot deal with such files. You will need to transcode to a standard and constant frame rate for blender to work with your file.

Or you can try using another video editing app (blender's video editing capabilities are not as developed as other apps out there).

Comment: Converted to constant frame rate and playback seems to work in the VSE. I'm not sure if it'll work when everything is rendered, but I have high hopes. Thanks!